# Можно ли создать массив указателей, которые указывают на обьекты разных классов?

Tags: ооп, указатели, c++

Добрый вечер! Кто-нибудь делал что-то подобное? Я создал массив указателй `void *pointer[10];` и Сделал так `pointer[0]=&ob1; pointer[1]=&ob2;... где ob1, ob2..` - объекты разных классов... Задача состоит в том, чтобы можно было обращаться через указатели к полям и методам классов, на объекты которые они ссылаются. Например `pointer[0]->ob1_func();` Вызываем метод первого объекта. Как это сделать? Пробовал по всякому, не получается.

Comment: Вы можете создать массив указателей на общего родителя Ваших классов (полиморфизм включения, отношение 'is a'). Разумеется с помощью ломика (сишный cast) Вы можете запихать самые разные указатели в один массив, но так лучше не делать. Изврат, весьма глупый и опасный.

Comment: А можно сделать что-то наподобии такого: 

class A{

...
class B:public A{

}obj_b;

}a; ?  

Конечно это еще тот изврат))), но всё же... У меня не получилось...

Comment: @alexlz: зачем каст? http://ideone.com/fYJgi3

Comment: @VladD Во-первых cast там есть, хотя и неявный. Во-вторых, там идёт приведение типа-потомка к типу-родителю. Я писал про приведение к указателю на вообще чужой тип (т.е. B не является наследником A). Сишный cast сделает это без звука. (Но делать так не следует)

Comment: @alexlz: ну, там происходит неявный cast, который даже слабее, чем `static_cast`, и совсем не злой (всё же `B` _является_ `A`). Приводить к указателю на неродственный тип, конечно, не стоит, согласен на 200%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно в массиве хранить не просто указатели, а "полуумные указатели". Эти указатели будут обычным классом, который будет состоять из двух полей - собственно указателя на объект и числа, которое будет идентифицировать тип объекта.

```
struct hspointer { // half-smart pointer
  void * pointer;
  int type;
};
```

Но возникает проблема - а как вызывать функции у объекта ? можно делать конечно тонны кастов, но это не выход. Для этого мы добавим этому классу новую функцию - `bool call(std::string func)`. Внутри этот функции, будем проверять тип объекта и строку-имя и вызывать нужную функцию у нужного объекта. На самом начальном этапе это все можно сделать на базе `case + case/if`,  а можно и на базе `std::map` (который при большом кол-ве типов и функций даст прирост и простоту). Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924844/stdmap-of-member-function-pointers) есть пример реализации.

Если реализация позволяет, тогда каждый класс может содержать свой map  со списком своих методов.

Плюсы:

- каждый объект заведует своими функциями, полностью контролирует их.
- Вызываемые функции могут быть приватными.
- В случае, функция не найдена, объект может вызвать свою личную.

Минусы:

- объекты желательно наследовать от одного общего предка, что бы функция call не делала постоянных кастов.

Второй способ заключается в том, что объекты не изменяются совсем, но функция `call` делает всю черновую работу.

Осталось решить несколько мелких проблем - что делать с аргументами и возвращаемым результатом. Собственно агрументы можно передать как [Variable Argument Lists](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson17.html). А результат может быть вторым аргументом. То есть, метод `call` будет такой:

```
bool call(std::string method, ...) {
    func = getFuncPointerByName(method);
    if (func == NULL)
       return false;
    va_list arguments;
    va_start ( arguments, method );
    func(arguments); // здесь можно навернуть различную магию.
    va_end(arguments);
    return true;
}
```

Но все таки не сильно хочется вызывать через отдельный метод. Поэтому можно перегрузить оператор `operator()`
В целом работы много, но в результате получится интересное решение. Но спросите себя, Вам реально такое нужно? Может быстрее будет разбросать объекты на два-три типа, сделать для них базовые классы, которые будут содержать все нужные функции и просто иметь два-три списка вместо одного.

Comment: Python in C++

Comment: типа того. я сам о питоне вспомнил, когда это сочинял:)

Answer (score 3):

Вот пример, как можно такое провернуть: http://ideone.com/UNOkpj. Но нужно ли? То что C++ позволяет такое делать, ещё не значит, что так делать стоит. Не представляю, где такое можно использовать. Пересмотрите логику вашего приложения, с ней что-то не так. Пихать разнородные объекты в один массив противоестественно.

Comment: Ну, это, для меня, смысла не имеет, т.к. ((  A*  )(p[0]))->a; Если было бы p[0]->a, то имело бы смысл...

Comment: Ваше p[0]->a не имеет смысла для компилятора. Откуда он, по вашему, узнает, объект какого класса лежит по указателю p[0]? Ведь в рантайме вы можете записать туда всё что угодно. Программа на C++ компилируется в машинный код, в котором даже само понятие "класс" не имеет смысла. Есть просто участок памяти, к которому обращается программа. А какой тип данных лежит по адресу p[0] машина во время выполнения не знает. Явный каст на этапе компиляции указывает, как воспринимать тот или иной участок памяти, но во время выполнения такое провернуть невозможно.